# How to cascade a client-side validation on embeddedForm on Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, cascade, client-side-validation

I have 2 forms built with buildForm.

Here is `Score` buildForm:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('mesPoints','integer',array('required' => true))
            ->add('pointsAdversaire','integer',array('required' => true));
}
```

Here is `Combat` buildForm:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('tour','integer')
            ->add('score',new CompetitionCombatScoreType(),array('required' => false));
}
```

When i create a `Score`, if i don't fill `mesPoints` and `pointsAdversaire` i have a popup that indicate me that i have to filled those both fields.

When i create a `Score` from a `Combat`, I only have the doctrine exception.

If I had constraints on `Score` model and i had `'cascade_validation' => true` on `Combat` buildForm `DefaultOptions`, the page reload and tell me that i have to filled the field.

But I can't manage to have the same result that i have when creating diretly a score : with the popup from client-side validation.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

1st case is managed by client native HTML5 fields validation - inputs have `required` attribute.

In 2nd case you marked `score` as not required, so child inputs don't have `required` attribute and that's why client side validation pass `score` with empty values.